# Why my text disappears halfway in the UserAccountsDrawerHeader in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am using a drawer with UserAccountsDrawerHeader but for some reason my text keeps disappearing every time I want to do it below.
The text information is shown using future builder.
If the information of my text was not from the future builder, it works correctly.
I have an error in the `accountName` property.

How could I solve that?

Code and image::

```dart
class namecabeceradrawer extends State<NameCabeceraDrawer> {
  Widget NameUserDrawer() {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 42),
      child: Text(nameusuario),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: FutureBuilder(
          future: futureServices,
          builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
            List listainfocabeceradrawer = snapshot.data;
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return Center(
                child: Container(
                  child: ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: listainfocabeceradrawer.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                        nameusuario = listainfocabeceradrawer[i].NameUsuario;
                        return Container(
                          child: NameUserDrawer(),
                        );
                      }),
                ),
              );
            } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return Text("${snapshot.error}");
            }
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          }),
    );
    throw UnimplementedError();
  }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you check `NameUserDrawer` if it is having fixed height

Comment: I updated my code, added a line of code that I was missing in the NameUserDrawer and added another image.

I want it to look like the 2nd image (the information in the second image is not from the database)

Comment: I think it has something to do with the future builder, because if it's a simple Text, it doesn't give problems with the desig

Answer (score 0):

You can remove/reduce the margin of Container.  You may prefer using `padding` instead

```dart
Widget NameUserDrawer() {
  return Container(
    // margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 42), //here
    child: Text(nameusuario),
  );
}
```

Comment: I already tried to use it, the problem is that every time I click below, the text disappears.
When I use a normal text without the future, or it gives an error in the layout

Comment: Failed to test it. Can you include dummy future with sample data that will reproduce the same issue

Comment: I do not understand what do you need? what part of the code?

Comment: create a simple widget with [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: what i posted is a fictional example

Comment: sorry,need proper snippet that will  reproduce the issue